# How to set date (for current day as highlighted) on calendar for jquery datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

I'm using the Trent Richardson's datetimepicker [here](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).  How can I set the date on the calendar?  The following sets the time correctly but the date as highlighted as current day is not getting set.  In this particular example I'm hijacking the "now" button click to set the current UTC date/time.

```
$.datepicker._gotoToday = function (id) {
var inst = this._getInst($(id)[0]),
$dp = inst.dpDiv;
this._base_gotoToday(id);
var tp_inst = this._get(inst, 'timepicker');
var now = new Date();
var now_utc = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
//
// Time gets set correctly but the date highlight for current day is not getting set in the calendar picker.
this._setTime(inst, now_utc);
$('.ui-datepicker-today', $dp).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Trent Richardson's datetimepicker relies on the jQueryUI, I presume its methods and settings are related. So,

Perhaps something like:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" );
```

OR

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    defaultDate: 1,
```

This might not be what you're looking for, just brainstorming.

References:
[jUI defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)
[setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: thx, hijacking $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "setDate", "10/12/2012" ); worked great!

Comment: one quick ask, what I really need to to set the default date (the one that defaults to today) instead of setdate.  The one with the highlighted circle I want changed once the user views the datetimepicker. http://bit.ly/UoukSK

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that. Try making that a separate question and perhaps someone else will have that answer for you.